# create an authenticated http client with the firebase Id Token in flutter

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

how to create an authenticated http client with firebase id token in flutter so that you can deal with google apis

I retrieved the firebase token and now I want to obtain an authenticated http client in order to be able to perform actions with the google api

```
Future<void> _getFirebaseIdToken() async {
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

    if (user != null) {
      String? token = await user.getIdToken();
      print(token);
      setState(() {
        _firebaseIdToken = token!;
      });
    }
  }
```

please help me find a solution